# How to put full screen mode in powerpoint with java

Tags: java, ms-office, powerpoint, fullscreen

I want to send F5 when i insert a number in a FieldText to open a Powerpoint in full screen. And if i want to open a .ppt it doesnt work because i dont know how to change between .ppt and .pptx.

```
 private void btnAcceptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try {

        File f;
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        String s =txtNumar.getText().toString()+".pptx";// here i want to choose   
                     // between ppt or pptx. Right now it only runs with .pptx.
        f=new File(s);
        if (f.exists()) {

            Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F5);//tried to send F5 but didnt work.

        } else{

            if (txtNumar.getText().isEmpty()){
                java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nu ai introdus un numar de cantare corect", "Lipseste un numar de cantare", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nu exista cantarea", "Lipseste cantarea", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(miAplic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to supply more information about what you're trying to do, specifically with regard to what you're trying to do by switching between .ppt and pptx. As for pressing F5, look into Java's Robot class to simulate keypresses.

Comment: You could also just save the powerpoint as a `.pps` file. That would open into a show automatically.

Comment: we have like 1000 ppt so it´s gona be hard save all to .pps. i tried the Robot class but dosent send F5.

Comment: @catluc Robot does indeed send function keys. Make sure that Robot puts PowerPoint in the foreground before attempting to send the key (simulate a keypress in PowerPoint's title bar), otherwise, you're sending F5 to your OS or someplace else.

Comment: @MarsAtomic i dont know how to do that.

Comment: i just fixed the F5 part by adding some delay on the robot.